# Cannot get Background Audio work in WP81 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, background-audio

I am migrating a Windows Phone 7.8  application from to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight - and ultimately possibly to Windows Phone 10..

But now I am stuck in a triviality of not getting Background Audio Player to work in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight at all. 
This probably is something obvious  - but after  a few days of experimentation I am running out of ideas.

What happens is that I get error message

System.InvalidOperationException: E_FAIL -2146233079

from player when setting audio track.

Essential code snippets

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    BackgroundAudioPlayer player;
    Uri _trackUri;
    Uri _albumArtUri;
    string _trackUriString = "http://podcast.cbc.ca/mp3/hourlynews.mp3";
    string _albumArtUriString = "http://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/images/promo-hourlies.jpg";
    string _trackAlbum = "Album - Podcast news";
    string _trackArtist = "Artist - CBC";
    string _trackTitle = "Track title - Hourly news";
    string _tag = "testtag";
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance;
        _trackUri = new Uri(_trackUriString, UriKind.Absolute);
        _albumArtUri = new Uri(_albumArtUriString, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
    private void SetTrack_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Track = createTrack();       // player gets error after this statement
    }
    private AudioTrack createTrack()
    {
        return new AudioTrack(_trackUri, _trackTitle, _trackArtist, _trackAlbum, _albumArtUri, _tag, EnabledPlayerControls.All);
    }
```

I created this in VisualStudio 2015 Community solution with two Silverlight 8.1 projects using the built in templates. And yes, background audio project is referenced from main program. [link to project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=92741062A0AF3DD6!115343&authkey=!AEVlPJB8Uf7FMT0&ithint=file%2Czip)

To check my sanity I created - in a similar way - a WP7.8 project ([link to project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=92741062A0AF3DD6!115342&authkey=!AB8hHW4aCVXdbfI&ithint=file%2Czip)) using VS12 Express. And copied the code over from VS15 side. That application works fine.

Ideas appreciated - very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally got into looking into this question more.. And there it was.. The answer.. Plain and simple: Not supported this way.. In [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642084%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) they say

> "AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent not supported for
> Silverlight 8.1 apps
>
> The AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent
> classes, which supported background audio playback for Windows Phone 8
> apps, are not supported in Silverlight 8.1. If you want to support
> background audio playback, you can continue to use a Windows Phone 8
> app or create a Windows Phone Store app, which supports new background
> audio APIs."

So that is it.. :(